# Erro 6118 no promt de comando

Tags: .net

Estou tentando ver os servidores conectados no meu host pelo cmd, porém quando eu uso o comando "net view" aparece a mensagem de erro.

"Erro de sistema 6118.

A lista de servidores para este grupo de trabalho não está disponível no momento"

ja tentei desabilitar o firewall do windows.
ja tentei executar como adm e usar o comando "sc config browser start=auto"
e nada funcionou, como resolver e conseguir ver quem esta conectado no meu roteador?

Comment: Vá aqui neste link que vou deixar, resolveu o meu problema e poderá resolver o seu.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hTWATFsUV6M
áhhhh, logo depois de fazer o procedimento, não esquece de colocar o cmd no modo administrador pra testar se retirou o erro.
espero ter ajudado... abraço

Answer (score 0):

É exatamente o q vc falou na pergunta, a lista de servidores não está disponível, vc pode estar fora do grupo, aconselho:

Verifique se cada pc está no mesmo workgroup;
Desabilite o firewall e o antivirus em cada PC;
Execute um Ping para PC2 apartir do PC1 para garantir que a rede esteja ok;
Execute um Net View para PC2 apartir do PC1 verifique se está ok.